# Get parameter to dictionary function

Tags: python, dictionary, parameters

Hi i am writing program for separating values of current and voltage from serial messages from some device. I eliminate a lot of if|elif using dictionaries.I am calling function getValues from main while function and giving this function parameter msg (stored message from serial port). I have error in function **def V1** that variable doesn't exist. I am new in python and still learning. Is there some option to pass msg parameter in dictionaris fuction or something similar?

```py
def getValues(msg,typeVal,corI3,corI2,corI1):
    busValues = {'V1':V1,
                 'V2':V2,
                 'V3':V3,
                 'I1':I1,
                 'I2':I2,
                 'I3':I3,
                 'Vb':Vb,
                 'Vl':Vl,
                 'a':a,
                 'Va':Va,
                 'Ia':Ia,
                 'Ib':Ib}
    busValues.get(typeVal)(typeVal)

def V1(value):
    global index
    global strEnd1
    global strEnd2
    global strEnd3
    index = msg.find('V1:')
    strEnd1 = 30+corI3+corI2+corI1
    strEnd2 = 31+corI3+corI2+corI1
    strEnd3 = 32+corI3+corI2+corI1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you only need to add `msg` to your functions arguments. Same applies for `cor` parameters you seem to need. That would give you:

```
def V1(value, msg, corI3, corI2, corI1):
```

From there, you should be able to call it as:

```
busValues.get(typeVal)(typeVal, msg, corI3, corI2, corI1)
```

Comment: You are right. I tried this before i wrote there this question and in doesn't work. Now it worked, so fault was probably somewhere else. Thanks for solution.